# Php function including if statements and return

Tags: php, if-statement, return

Why do I get error in syntax from the code below:

```
<?php>
function wpai_package($price, $pack) {
    if($pack!=' '){
        return ($pack * $price);
    } else {
        return($price)
    }
}
?>
```

Syntax error unexpected'}' on line 8

I want to say if the pack IS NOT EMPTY (null) then price x pack otherwise price.

Thanks

Comment: post the error.

Comment: Syntax error unexpected '}'

Comment: try `empty()` function to check

Comment: edit your question to add the error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Parse/Syntax Errors; and How to solve them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change Your Code To

```
<?php


function wpai_package($price, $pack) {

    if(!empty($pack))
    {
        return ($pack * $price);
    } else {
        return $price;
    }
}

wpai_package(2,45);
```

**[Live Demo](https://eval.in/940658)**

And Also You Should Have to LEarn Return At here http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php

Comment: This one gives no error but all the prices where the pack is null come 0

Comment: So what would you expect ?

Answer (score 1):

you missed an ; near return

```
 <?php
function wpai_package($price, $pack) {
   if(!empty($pack)){
     return ($pack * $price);
   } else {
     return($price);

   }
}
?>
```

Comment: This one gives no error but all the prices where the pack is null come 0

Comment: could you share more info

Answer (score 0):

In the first line you added a `>` after `<?php` which has to be removed.

In line 7 the semicolon is missing at the end of the line.